# Android billing consuming items

Tags: java, android

I am trying to have an consumable item for my app.
i currently use this code:

```
private void BuyManager() {
        mHelper.flagEndAsync();
            mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, "jm.admin", 1011, new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase info) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder succces = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    int proccesed = 1;
                    try {
                        proccesed=mservice.consumePurchase(3,getPackageName(), "inapp:"+getPackageName()+":jm.admin");
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String succs = "nee";
                    if (proccesed==0){
                        succs = "ja";
                    }
                    succces.setMessage("We checken uw aankoop Aankoop gegevens: " + result + " Aankoop succesvol: "+succs);
                    succces.setPositiveButton("Oke", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


              @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                succces.show();
                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder succces2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    succces2.setMessage("Uw aankoop is voltooid");
                    succces2.setPositiveButton("Oke", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
                    succces2.show();
                }
            }
    });
}
```

but when i buy the item it not consumed at all and it haves the code 7 response (item already bought).
Whats wrong with my code?